# DataTemplate with TextBlock, ContentControl.ContentStringFormat is ignored

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

I have the following datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SectionHeader">
    <Border CornerRadius="5">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF1E5270" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF3E7595"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" Padding="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

and I can use it as follows

```
<ContentControl Content="Summary" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SectionHeader}" />
```

This works fine. But when I try to do the following

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedOrder}" ContentStringFormat="Details for Order \{0\}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SectionHeader}" />
```

I do not get the the full string only the order number. 
Is there a way to make this work with a single datatemplate or do I need to create a second data template?

Answer (score 0):

See [MSDN documentation on ContentControl.ContentStringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx):

> If you set the `ContentTemplate` or `ContentTemplateSelector` property of a `ContentControl`, the `ContentStringFormat` property is ignored.

Instead of relying on `ContentStringFormat`, you should either add `StringFormat` to your binding or create a trivial `StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter` and set binding's `Converter` and `ConverterParameter` properties, in case `Binding.StringFormat` doesn't work (it has non-obvious limitations too — it's used only when target property is of type `String`).

For example:

```
<Control.Resources>
    <a:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter"/>
</Control.Resources>
<!-- ... -->
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding SelectedOrder,
        Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter},
        ConverterParameter='Details for Order {0}'}"
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SectionHeader}"/>
```

You can use [this implementation of `StringFormatConverter`](https://github.com/Athari/Alba.Framework/blob/516426e4782659dfb1413c131528e9eb6a754b6d/Alba.Framework.Presentation/Windows/Markup/Converters/StringFormatConverter.cs).

Comment: I already tried setting the Content of the ContentControl to `Content="{Binding SelectedOrder, StringFormat='Details for Order \{0\}'}"` but it does not work.

Comment: @AlanRutter `ContentControl.Content` is of type `object`, not `string`, so I guess `Binding.StringFormat` doesn't work either. You can still use a custom converter. I've added an example to my answer.